# How can `SqlProvider` take more than 1 param in `MyBatis`?

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

When I was trying to use `SqlProvider` I got an exception `org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException`( says "`There is no getter for property named 'providerTakesParameterObject' in 'class org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.ProviderSqlSource'`"). I googled it and it seems that a `SqlProvider` can not take more than one argument. Here is the demo code:

MyTableMapper.java

```
public interface MyTableMapper{
    @SelectProvider(type=MyTableSqlProvider.class, method="selectSelective")
    List<MyTable> selectSelective(Date from, Date to, String searchkey);
}
```

MyTableSqlProvider.java

```
public class MyTableSqlProvider{
    public String selectSelective(Date from, Date to, String name) {
    return new SQL() {{
        SELECT("*");
        FROM("MyTable");
        if(from!=null){
            WHERE("createtime >= {#from,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}");
        }
        if(to!=null){
            WHERE("createtime <= {#to,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}");
        }
        if(!StringUtils.isBlank(name)){
            WHERE("title like %{#name,jdbcType=VARCHAR}%");
        }
    }}.toString();
}
}
```

The codes above can't run. But how can I make it take all the args?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason. It's not `MyBatis`'s bug. I used a plugin [Mybatis-PageHelper](https://github.com/pagehelper/Mybatis-PageHelper). The old version of plugin can not support the `MyBatis 3.4.0`. I update the plugin and it is correct now.